# Maximum computation

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for the the supremum of the expression $x+y+z$,  all real numbers, under the constraints $x^2+y^2=1$ and $z\leq y\leq x$. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You can take $z$ as big as you can till $z=y$ and it doesn't affect the constraint , so your problem reduces to maximize $x+2y$  given $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x\geq y$.

Comment: So writing $x=r.cos(u)$ and $y=r.sin(u)$ we are done to maximizing $cos(u)+2.sin(u)$...am I right?

Comment: another constraint is there, $\tan(u)\geq 1\implies \pi/4\leq u\leq \pi/2$

Comment: Right, so this gives us $u=Arctan(2)$, hence the maximum should be $cos(Arctan(2))+2.sin(Arctan(2))$...?

Comment: @Tina: Since $\pi/4\leq\arctan(2)\leq\pi/2$, you got it right.